# Передача объекта аргументом

Tags: c++, ооп

Итак, надо передать объект аргументом. Я его передал, но в методе должно измениться одно поле объекта. Но после выполнения метода оно не изменяется. Что тут делать?
Вот код

```
    void adding(MainC *MainCobj) { //2+1 ->3
      if (MainCobj->n > MainCobj->m)
        k = n; 
      else
        k = m;
      for (i = 0;i < k;i++) {
        MainCobj->c = MainCobj->a + MainCobj->b;
      }
      cout << "adding:" << c[1]<<endl;
      cout << "cc=" << MainCobj->c[1]<<endl;//cc= Это для проверки добавления
   }
```

Comment: Что такое `MainC`? Создайте минимальный пример, воспроизводящий ошибку, тогда, возможно, Вам помогут быстрее.

Comment: MainC - родительский класс. Ошибка в том что в массив С ничего не меняется после выполнения метода. Т.е. в методе сс="Какое-то значение" а если передать объект в другой метод - в "С" пусто

Comment: for (i = 0;i < k;i++) {
        MainCobj->c = MainCobj->a + MainCobj->b;
      }

Вы не забыли индексироваться по c?

Comment: И да, еще: в данном примере нет ООП. Здесь есть классы, как контейнеры. Но никакого ООП;)